# Error using SSL and Tomcat on web-portal

Tags: tomcat, ssl, tomcat7

I have a web-portal. Every user must authorize to use all the features of the portal. So every user must have a personal certificate. There is a link ***`Sign in`*** on my site. And if the user have a certificate everything goes well. But if he doesn't I get the blank page (standart `Web page is not available`) and in the `Tomcat 7.0` log I have this error

```
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing 
errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
```

In this situation I'd like to create an error page on my portal, e.g.  *`The page you requested was not found! Back to homepage!`*. But I don't know how.

Here my `server.xml SSL` configuration

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Maybe I can not completely understand how does the SSL and Tomcat actually work. What this error is about and how to solve my problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do redirecting to what ever page you want by creating servelt and mapping that to welcome file. this is how it can be achieved. In your web.xml you should do some thing like this

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>UrlRedirectServlet </servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.UrlRedirectServlet </servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UrlRedirectServlet </servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

and create a servlet  some thing like below

```
public class UrlRedirectServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    public UrlRedirectServlet() {
        super();
    }       

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        urlRedirecting(request, response);
    }   

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        urlRedirecting(request, response);

    }   

 private void   urlRedirecting(request , respone)
{ //do what ever you want
}

}
```

Hope this helps
Get back if you have any queries
Mohan

Comment: By the way are trying to do  certificate based login ? 
Second thing from your connector port i could not see server certificate ? 
If clientauth is false it ignore client certificates.
Reference
[link](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html)

Comment: I don't use login/password, just client certificate. So you say, that I must have a server certificate. If the client has his own certificate, the server one is ignoring. And if the client doesn't have his certificate, the server one is using? Сorrectly?

Comment: No. It works based on mutual authentication, client and server should have valid certificates. In order to build successful handshake. if both trust each other then only you will be able to login into application. hope it clears. 
Show me tomcat configuration?

Comment: Thanks, it's clear. And what if client doesn't have his certificate? Which particular Tomcat configuration settings do you need?

Comment: You can define servlet as given above so you can play with it. you can control url redirect at your finger tips in all the cases. 

In general it will consider secondary login type if exist or else error page.
Cheers!